# EntityFramework: How to map a Zero-to-One relationship?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the below database tables:

```
FundAllocation {below two columns make a composite primary key}
       [CurrencyRefId] (int)  {FK to a table Currency.CurrencyId}
       [AllocationRefId] (int) {FK to Allocation.AllocationId}

Allocation
       [AllocationId] (int) {PK Identity Column}
       [AllocationTitle] (varchar)
```

Below are my entities corresponding to the above table:

```
public class FundAllocation
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CurrencyRefId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int AllocationRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AllocationRefId")]
    public Allocation Allocation { get; set; }
}

public class Allocation
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AllocationId { get; set; }
    public string AllocationTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I get the FundAllocation list from the data context, its Allocation property is set to null. What additional configuration is needed to achieve this Zero-to-One relationship ?

Comment: not sure to understand zero to one (mean zero or one ?), but try `public virtual Allocation Allocation { get; set; }`.

Comment: @tschmit007, the virtual keyword worked. Thanks. I actually wanted the FundAllocation to 'require' an Allocation, but the Allocation will not have a navigation property back to FundAllocation. Hence I coined the term zero-to-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you must populate the property by:

- enabling lazy loading:

  - `public virtual Allocation Allocation { get; set; }`
- eager loading :

  - [eagerly loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager)